# Como editar registros do MySQL com uma tabela PHP fora da ordem

Tags: php, mysql

Estou criando um sistema de solicitações de documentos, e nele tem uma página onde mostra todas as solicitações pendentes. Essas solicitações estão registradas em uma tabela do MySQL e mostrada como na imagem abaixo.

[image: Os dados são exibidos por ordem do ID.]

O problema é que no campo "Ações" só é possível executar algo na ordem da tabela (Emprestar ou Apagar o primeiro, para depois conseguir fazer isso com o próximo e assim por diante).

> Emprestar = Insere em outra tabela (MySQL) e deleta da tabela (MySQL) de pedidos
>
> Apagar = Apaga da tabela de pedidos

Como faço para conseguir executar a ação em qualquer um da lista, sem precisar respeitar a ordem dos registros mostrados?

Comandos que estou utilizando:

```
$resultado  = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM pedidos ORDER BY  'id'");
$linhas     = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
$linhas1    = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
```

Formulário/Tabela

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
    <?php
    while($linhas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){

        $data = $linhas['dataHora'];
        $data = strtotime($data);
        echo "<tr>";
        /* echo "<td><input type='checkbox' class='checkthis' /></td>";*/
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td>".$linhas['pasta']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$linhas['codigoPaciente']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$linhas['nomePaciente']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$linhas['motivo']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$linhas['solicitante']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$linhas['setor']."</td>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$linhas['id_pedidos']."'>";
        echo "<td>".date('d/m/Y - H:i', $data)."</td>";
        echo "<td>  <input type='submit' tittle='Emprestar'  value='E' name='SendEmprestar' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'> <input type='submit' value='A' name='SendDelete' class='btn btn-sm btn-warning'>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</form>";
        }
    ?>
```

Processar a solicitação

```
        <?php
        $SendEmprestar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'SendEmprestar', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if($SendEmprestar){
$id         =  isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : ''; 
$resultado  = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE id_pedidos = $id");
$linhas     = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
$linhas     = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

$id_pedidos     = $linhas['id_pedidos'];
$pasta          = $linhas['pasta'];
$nomePaciente   = $linhas['nomePaciente'];
$solicitante    = $linhas['solicitante'];
$motivo         = $linhas['motivo'];
$codigoPaciente = $linhas['codigoPaciente'];
$setor          = $linhas['setor'];
$colaborador    = isset($_SESSION['nome']) ? $_SESSION['nome'] : '';

$emprestar = "
INSERT INTO emprestados(
        pasta, 
        nomePaciente, 
        solicitante, 
        motivo, 
        codigoPaciente,
        setor,
        colaborador) 
VALUES ('$pasta', 
        '$nomePaciente', 
        '$solicitante', 
        '$motivo', 
        '$codigoPaciente',
        '$setor',
        '$colaborador')";
$pendente = "
INSERT INTO pendentes(
        pasta, 
        nomePaciente, 
        solicitante, 
        motivo, 
        codigoPaciente,
        setor,
        colaborador) 
VALUES ('$pasta', 
        '$nomePaciente', 
        '$solicitante', 
        '$motivo', 
        '$codigoPaciente',
        '$setor',
        '$colaborador')";

$salvar     = mysqli_query($conexao, $emprestar);   
$salvar2    = mysqli_query($conexao, $pendente);
if ($salvar and $salvar2 =! 0){
            $query      =   mysqli_query($conexao, "DELETE FROM pedidos WHERE id_pedidos = $id");
                    if($query != 0){
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>";
                    echo "Emprestado com sucesso!";
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "<script>deletePedido()</script>";
}else{
                    echo "Solicitação invalída.";
                    echo "<script>deletePedido()</script>"; 
        }
}else{
                    echo "Erro na solicitação!";
                    echo "<script>deletePedido()</script>"; 
}               }


        $SendDelete = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'SendDelete', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if($SendDelete){
                $id         =  isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : ''; 
                $query      =   mysqli_query($conexao, "DELETE FROM pedidos WHERE id_pedidos = $id");
                if($query != 0){
                        echo "<div class='alert alert-warning' role='alert'>";
                        echo "Pedido excluído com sucesso!";
                        echo "<script>deletePedido()</script>";
                        echo "</div>";
                }else{
                        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>";
                        echo "Solicitação invalída.";
                        echo "<script>deletePedido()</script>";
                        echo "</div>";
                }
        }

?>
```

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta. Reformule, por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da forma que seu formulário está sendo construído,

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
    ..............
    ..............
    <tr>
    <td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='1'> 
    <input type='submit' tittle='Emprestar'  value='E' name='SendEmprestar' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'>
    <input type='submit' value='A' name='SendDelete' class='btn btn-sm btn-warning'>
    </tr>
</form>
    
    ............
    ............
    <tr>
    <td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='2'>
    <input type='submit' tittle='Emprestar'  value='E' name='SendEmprestar' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'>
    <input type='submit' value='A' name='SendDelete' class='btn btn-sm btn-warning'>
    </tr>
</form>

................
................
```

somente a primeira linha da tabela será possível submeter o formulário.

> Motivo pelo qual quando deleta a primeira linha você consegue realizar o proximo e assim sucessivamente

Observe que na segunda linha só há a tag de fechamento `</form>`

Faça dessa forma abaixo (já que há vários inputs com `name='id'`)

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
    ..............
    ..............
    <tr>
    <td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='1'> 
    <input type='submit' tittle='Emprestar'  value='E' name='SendEmprestar' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'>
    <input type='submit' value='A' name='SendDelete' class='btn btn-sm btn-warning'>
    </tr>
</form>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
    ............
    ............
    <tr>
    <td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='2'>
    <input type='submit' tittle='Emprestar'  value='E' name='SendEmprestar' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'>
    <input type='submit' value='A' name='SendDelete' class='btn btn-sm btn-warning'>
    </tr>
  </form>


................
................
```

** Seu PHP**

```
while($linhas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
  echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\">";
    $data = $linhas['dataHora'];
    $data = strtotime($data);
    echo "<tr>";
    /* echo "<td><input type='checkbox' class='checkthis' /></td>";*/
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td>".$linhas['pasta']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$linhas['codigoPaciente']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$linhas['nomePaciente']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$linhas['motivo']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$linhas['solicitante']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$linhas['setor']."</td>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$linhas['id_pedidos']."'>";
    echo "<td>".date('d/m/Y - H:i', $data)."</td>";
    echo "<td>  <input type='submit' tittle='Emprestar'  value='E' name='SendEmprestar' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'> <input type='submit' value='A' name='SendDelete' class='btn btn-sm btn-warning'>";
    echo "</tr>";
   echo "</form>";
 }
```

> Importante: A variável `$ _SERVER ["PHP_SELF"]` pode ser usada por hackers!

Como evitar?

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

[Mais informações](https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_form_validation.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado.
Não havia me atentado ao fato de ter colocado o `</form>` dentro do PHP, coloquei ele fora, fechando o formulário como um todo, e funcionou.

[EDIT]

Não havia entendido muito bem o que você citou sobre a construção do meu formulário. Fiz o procedimento que citei acima e achei que o problema estava resolvido, mas na verdade, antes de fazer isso se eu clicasse em algum input, que não fosse o primeiro, não recebia nenhum retorno. Ao colocar o `</form>` fora do PHP, os inputs retornaram ações, mas só no último registro da tabela.

Refiz meu formulário como você mencionou e agora está tudo certo.

Muito obrigado!!